# Specflow global tag?

Tags: c#, specflow

Please this simple `scenario`:

```
@Chrome
Scenario: Simple Calculation
    Given user
    When User login to the system
    And ....
```

So i have many `scenarios`, each scenario use default `Browser` or specific one (in this example the `Browser` is `Chrome`)
So i have several `URLs` than i am checking so i looking for way to define global `Tag` what will represent `URL` and inside `.cs` file this `Tag` will converted into my `URL` (and as i mentioned before i have several).

And i want to use it this way:

**@GlobalURL**

```
@Chrome
Scenario: Simple Calculation
    Given user
    When User login to the 'GlobalURL'
    And ....
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `@GlobalURL` tag for scenarios, then you can add method with annotation: `[BeforeScenario]` and in this method get that hook, and depending on it's value get correct `url`. In my project I made a separate class - TestConfiguration, which properties (base url, key, what kind of test) and filled from tags before every scenario, and then used in test.

Also you can in scenario send parameter and based on it choose url in the code.